# How to set up registry in a multi-host microk8s cluster?

Tags: docker-registry

I used microk8s to set up a kubernetes cluster with three virtualbox machines in it. Everything seems to be fine, but the microk8s registry does not seem to work anymore. It used to work on a single machine, but I am not sure if it is meant to work for a multi-host cluster. Anyways, below is what happened (under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with microk8s installed by `sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.27`):

Initially `microk8s status` shows that the registry is disabled:

```
$ microk8s status 
microk8s is running
high-availability: yes
  datastore master nodes: 192.168.10.30:19001 192.168.10.31:19001 192.168.10.32:19001
  datastore standby nodes: none
addons:
  enabled:
    dns                  # (core) CoreDNS
    ha-cluster           # (core) Configure high availability on the current node
    helm                 # (core) Helm - the package manager for Kubernetes
    helm3                # (core) Helm 3 - the package manager for Kubernetes
    hostpath-storage     # (core) Storage class; allocates storage from host directory
    storage              # (core) Alias to hostpath-storage add-on, deprecated
  disabled:
    cert-manager         # (core) Cloud native certificate management
    community            # (core) The community addons repository
    dashboard            # (core) The Kubernetes dashboard
    gpu                  # (core) Automatic enablement of Nvidia CUDA
    host-access          # (core) Allow Pods connecting to Host services smoothly
    ingress              # (core) Ingress controller for external access
    kube-ovn             # (core) An advanced network fabric for Kubernetes
    mayastor             # (core) OpenEBS MayaStor
    metallb              # (core) Loadbalancer for your Kubernetes cluster
    metrics-server       # (core) K8s Metrics Server for API access to service metrics
    minio                # (core) MinIO object storage
    observability        # (core) A lightweight observability stack for logs, traces and metrics
    prometheus           # (core) Prometheus operator for monitoring and logging
    rbac                 # (core) Role-Based Access Control for authorisation
    registry             # (core) Private image registry exposed on localhost:32000
```

But when I use `microk8s` to enable it, there is an error:

```
$ microk8s enable registry
Infer repository core for addon registry                                        
Infer repository core for addon hostpath-storage                                
Addon core/hostpath-storage is already enabled                                  
The registry will be created with the size of 20Gi.                             
Default storage class will be used.                                             
Warning: Detected changes to resource container-registry which is currently being deleted.
namespace/container-registry unchanged
Warning: Detected changes to resource registry-claim which is currently being deleted.
persistentvolumeclaim/registry-claim unchanged
configmap/local-registry-hosting unchanged
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "STDIN": deployments.apps "registry" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace container-registry because it is being terminated
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "STDIN": services "registry" is forbidden: unable to create new content in namespace container-registry because it is being terminated
```

`microk8s disable registry` seems to work fine, but re-enabling registry gives the same error:

```
$ microk8s disable registry
Infer repository core for addon registry
Addon core/registry is already disabled
```

My questions are:

Is the built-in microk8s registry supposed to work in a multi-host cluster?

If not, how to set up an image registry in a multi-host microk8s cluster?